# Creating an SQL Server Error Log using sp_readerror from multiple servers SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am attempting to create one single database to store all login errors.

```
    insert into [dbo].[SQL_ErrorLog]
    exec sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'error'
```

The above code gets me the information that I need for the current long and I understand that changing the 0 to a 1,2....etc will get me the previous days logs.

I have 4 different environments and instead of setting this same job up on each environment, I would like to control it all from 1 single job. I intend to add a field to determine which environment the log information is coming from.

I know that I could also set up staging tables on each environment and then run a select statement to pull in data from each staging table to the final table, however again I am trying to complete all the work from one environment if possible.

I have linked the other environments using the linked servers and can select data from any of them without a problem.

My question is more related on how I can run the exec sp_readerror stored procedure on the other server and insert that data into my master table.

An example would be:
Env0 - This is where the master table would be and where I would like to set everything up
Env1
Env2
Env3

I would like to be able to pull sp_readerror 0, 1, 'error' information from Env1, Env2, and Env3 and populate it on Env0 without using staging tables on each individual environment if possible.

Please let me know if this is not 100% clear. It makes sense in my head, however that does not always come out in text form. :)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: One issue could be, what happens when you run this and the error log has been cycled? Or, how are you going to not get duplicates? You'll need to limit it based off the dateTime and read each error log until you have gone back "as far as you need". I do something similar to email myself a daily error log. But regarding RPC, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771884/creating-an-sql-server-error-log-using-sp-readerror-from-multiple-servers-sql-se

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Seems like the link you sent is not found. I get a page not found error when trying to load it

Comment: not sure what happened, but i see what you mean. Here it is: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/06/sql-server-executing-remote-stored-procedure-calling-stored-procedure-on-linked-server/

Comment: Thank you for reposting the link. I will look it over and see what information I can find and go from there. If this resolves my question, then I will close it out. Many thanks :)

Comment: No worries at all. It’s a broad question with a few approaches for sure!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linked servers it seems like you could link together multiple calls using go from the main source server. This will work assuming your linked servers are linked off one server.

```
INSERT INTO [Linked Server Name]. [some database name].[dbo].[SQL_ErrorLog]
EXEC [Linked Server Name].[some database name].[dbo].sp_readerrorlog

GO

INSERT INTO [Linked Server Name2]. [some database name].[dbo].[SQL_ErrorLog]
EXEC [Linked Server Name2].[some database name].[dbo].sp_readerrorlog

GO


INSERT INTO [Linked Server Name3]. [some database name].[dbo].[SQL_ErrorLog]
EXEC [Linked Server Name3].[some database name].[dbo].sp_readerrorlog

GO

INSERT INTO [Linked Server Name4]. [some database name].[dbo].[SQL_ErrorLog]
EXEC [Linked Server Name4].[some database name].[dbo].sp_readerrorlog
```

I think this will be your best bet. You can use the agent and then put all of these into the agent job and run the job. They will need to be fully qualified in order to run on the correct linked server.